# How to create dynamic UITextField with different object name?

Tags: ios

I want to create dynamic UITextField with different object name.I have shown the code below for creating textfield dynamically. How can i create each textfield with different object name ?

```
for (int x=0; x < 4 ; x++)
    {

        CGRect txtFldFrame;
        if (x==0) 
            txtFldFrame=CGRectMake(385, 620, 278, 45);
        else
            txtFldFrame=CGRectMake(385, txtFldFrame.origin.y+60, 278, 45);
        [self createTxtImg:txtImgFrame createTextfield:txtFldFrame];
    }
```

In the 
createTextfield:(CGRect )txtfldframe
{

```
   UITextField *txtFld1=[[UITextField alloc]init];
txtFld1.frame=txtfldframe;
[txtFld1 setTag:textChk];
txtFld1.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
txtFld1.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
txtFld1.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
txtFld1.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:17/255.0 green:61/255.0 blue:83/255.0 alpha:1];
txtFld1.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:22];
txtFld1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
txtFld1.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
txtFld1.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
txtFld1.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
txtFld1.autocapitalizationType=UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
txtFld1.delegate = self;
[subScrollView addSubview:txtFld1];
```

}

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Can you provide examples?

Comment: Can you please make you question clearer? What do you mean with different object name?

Comment: can you please comment on the given answers, so that we know, we are on the right track?

Comment: This [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304358/how-to-create-uitextfield-dynamically-using-for-loop) solved my Problem.
I think this is what you are trying to do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is absolutely not a reason to create text fields with a different (unique name).
I'm pretty sure the reason you want the unique name, is so you can access them later in your code and edit their values, but here comes the trick: Use unique tag numbers.

Here is an example:

```
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    UITextField *myTextfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    myTextField.tag = 200+i;
    [self.view addSubview:myTextField];
}
```

Now we have created 4 text fields, which have tags 200, 201, 202 and 203

Later in code when we want to reference the second text field for example, all we have to do is this:

```
UITextField *myTextField = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:201];
```

now we have the control and we can get or set anything...

As a precaution I would suggest you check you actually got the UI element, by using:

```
if (!myTextField)
   return;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to create textbox:

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 12, 120, 25)];
[self.view addSubview:textField];
```

For another textbox just change the object name (textField)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand everything, because you gave not much information.

If you want to initialize multiple UITextFields:

```
UITextField *myTextField1 = [[UITextField alloc] init];  
UITextField *myTextField2 = [[UITextField alloc] init];  
UITextField *myTextField2 = [[UITextField alloc] init];
```

and so on...

If you want to do this on a random basis or a loop basis, i recommend to loop and put the objects into a dictionary with random keys like so:

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
    UITextField *myTextfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [myDict setObject:myTextfield forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myTextfield%d", i]];
    [myTextfield release];
}

NSLog(@"Dict: %@",myDict);
```