# Dynamically generate UITextFields

Tags: ios, objective-c, dynamic, programmatically-created

I am working on a app that need to generate UITextFields dynamically according to the json that recieved from a web service. Actually it is a view structure. It contains cordinates of the text field objects and their details. I am generating the structure using pre defined number of text fields.

```
 for (int i=0; i<[textFieldsArray count];i++) {

    NSDictionary *textFieldDict = [textFieldsArray objectAtIndex:i];

    switch (i+1) {
        case 1:
            textField1  = [[UITextField alloc]init];
            textField1.tag = i+1;
            textField1.text = [textFieldDict valueForKey:@"text"];
            textField1.frame = CGRectMake(posx,posy,textWidth,textHeight);
            [textField1 addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
            [self.imageView addSubview:textField1];
            break;
        case 2:
            textField2  = [[UITextField alloc]init];
            textField2.tag = i+1;
            textField2.text = [textFieldDict valueForKey:@"text"];
            textField2.frame = CGRectMake(posx,posy,textWidth,textHeight);
            [self.imageView addSubview:textField2];
            [textField2 addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
            break;
        case 3:
            textField3  = [[UITextField alloc]init];
            textField3.tag = i+1;
            textField3.text = [textFieldDict valueForKey:@"text"];
            textField3.frame = CGRectMake(posx,posy,textWidth,textHeight);
            [self.imageView addSubview:textField3];
            [textField3 addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }


}
```

I wanted to expand this into infinite text fields. Is there a way to create textfields dynamically.

Comment: You are creating text fields dynamically. I think what you are asking is more about the variables - you can store the textfield references in an NSMutableArray rather than individual UItextField variables

Comment: @Paulw11 can you help me to generate textfield array dynamically. I am struggling with naming textfield dynamically . As i heard we cant generate variable names dynamically at runtime.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304358/how-to-create-uitextfield-dynamically-using-for-loop look at this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<[textFieldsArray count];i++) {

    NSDictionary *textFieldDict = [textFieldsArray objectAtIndex:i];
    UITextField *textField  = [[UITextField alloc]init];
    textField.tag = i+1;
    textField.text = [textFieldDict valueForKey:@"text"];
    textField.frame = CGRectMake(posx,posy,textWidth,textHeight);
    [textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [self.imageView addSubview:textField];
}
```

You can get any text field using code below:

```
UITextField *textField  = (UITextField *)[self.imageView viewWithTag:1];
```